# Constructing a homology class of degree $d(d-1)/2$ in $H_3(S^3)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homology

There is a nice construction of a class of degree $d^2$ in $H_3(S^3)$. Take a class $h$ of degree $d$ in $H_1(S^1)$, and then take its join with itself: $h*h$ is degree $d^2$ in $H_3(S^1*S^1)$, and $S^1 * S^1$ is $S^3$.

I would like a similar construction of a class whose degree is $d(d-1)/2$.  The difference between the construction I described above and the one I want, seems formally like the distinction between tensor product and exterior product, but I don't know how to make any sense of that.

Comment: There is a construction of a degree $k$ map from $S^n \to S^n$ in example 2.31 of Hatcher's book here http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf

Comment: @PVAL Thanks, but I am looking for a construction which would be specifically for degrees of the form I mentioned, i.e., $d(d-1)/2$.  I think that, as there is for $d^2$, there might be some particularly nice construction for such degrees.

Comment: A short answer is to take the join of maps $S^1 \to S^1$ of degree $d$ and $\tfrac{d-1}{2}$ if $d$ is odd, and $\tfrac{d}{2}$ and $d-1$ if $d$ is even. The join is an isomorphism $S^{n-1} * S^{m-1} \to S^{n+m-1}$, and it's more closely related to the operation $(V,W) \mapsto V \times W$ on vector spaces than the tensor product: the join connects the unit sphere in $V$ to that in $W$. However, these are probably not getting at your underlying question.

Comment: @TylerLawson Thanks.  I guess I should have said that I am thinking of $d(d-1)/2$ as a binomial coefficient, and I would like a construction that in some way reflects that.

Comment: @HughThomas It's going to be somewhat complicated that you get a satisfactory answer since there seems to be no mathematical definition for 'nice' as used in your question, or at least you haven't provided one.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: The construction that I gave for a cycle of degree $d^2$ can be generalized to give a cycle of degree $d^n$ in $S^{2n-1}$.  Another feature which I would like is that it have should generalize in a similar way, giving a class of degree $d \choose n$ in $H_{2n-1}(S^{2n-1})$.

Comment: @HughThomas you're aware that $X*Y\simeq\Sigma X\wedge Y$, right?

Comment: @FernandoMuro: I don't grasp the meaning of your most recent comment.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The smash product of maps between circles is multiplicative wrt the degree and suspension preserves the degree, so just take the factors of your binomial coefficient and proceed as in your example, as Taylor indicated. To be honest, let me say again that I don't see a real question here.

Answer (score 1):

I am coming around to FernandoMuro's point of view that there are
a multitude of solutions, among which I haven't managed to specify 
sufficiently clearly which one(s) interest me.  (Thanks, FernandoMuro, and the other commenters, for your helpful responses.)

For example, take any 3-dimensional simplicial ball with $d \choose 2$ 
facets.  The space obtained by quotienting out the boundary is an 
$S^3$, and it admits a degree $d \choose 2$ map to a $S^3$ by sending each
simplex to $S^3$, sending the boundary of each simplex 
to a single point and the interior of each simplex to cover the $S^3$ (each with the same orientation).

I will record one specific example of such a simplical ball, because I rather like it.  Consider the simplicial complex whose vertex set is $\{1,\dots,d+2\}$, and whose facets are $\{i,i+1,j,j+1\}$ with
$1\leq i$, $\ i+1<j$, and $j+1\leq d+2$.  This is a triangulation of a 3-dimensional cyclic polytope with $d+2$ vertices; in fact it is the unique
such triangulation with $d\choose 2$ simplices.  (One sees that it is a
triangulation because it consists of the lower facets of a 4-dimensional cyclic polytope when one embeds the cyclic polytope in $\mathbb R^4$ in the usual way.)

I would still be interested in other solutions if anyone has any suggestions.